# Running tests on Dockerized Selenium Grid and want to run tests on specific browser versions

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to run tests on specific browser versions using a Dockerized Selenium Grid.

**Webdriver implementation**:

```java
    public static WebDriver get(String mode, String browser, String version) {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", Constants.getDownloadpath());
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnable=false");

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", Constants.getDownloadpath());
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
        FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();

        String remoteUrl = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");

            if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("remote")) {
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capabilities.setVersion(version);
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

                try {
                    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteUrl), capabilities);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            }
        }
    }
```

The method receives the browser version as an argument. Suppose I have two Chrome versions, v94.0 and v96.0, and I am using the parameters mode="remote", browser="chrome", and version="94.0". However, the tests seem to be running on a random node, even though I've specified the version explicitly.

**Selenium Grid docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.2-20220217
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  chrome96:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:96.0.4664.93
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  chrome94:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:94.0-chromedriver-94.0
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.1.2-20220217
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.1.2-20220217
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  firefox42:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.2.2-20220609
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.2-20220217
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

Can you help me understand why the tests are not running on the specified browser version, and what I can do to resolve this issue?

Below is a screenshot from the Selenium Grid hub showing the 2 Chrome nodes in question
[image: Selenium Grid hub with the 2 Chrome nodes]

Comment: Can you provide your docker-compose file or docker setup configuration

Comment: Done. Updated the question with my docker compose file. Please go through it.

Comment: use "browserVersion" when you set the capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome94:
image: selenium/node-chrome:94.0-chromedriver-94.0
shm_size: 2gb
depends_on:
  - selenium-hub
environment:
  - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
  - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
  - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
labels:
  - "browser=chrome"
  - "version=94.0"
volumes:
  - "G:/Downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads"
```

Added labels and this did the job for me.